# Can I create an instance of an object while declaring it?

Tags: java, php, object

Given this java snippet:

```
public class PDFObject {

/** the NULL PDFObject */
public static final PDFObject nullObj = new PDFObject(null, NULL, null);

..
}
```

How can I convert this into PHP? Is it possible to create an instance of an object while still declaring it?

Source File: http://code.google.com/p/txtreaderpdf/source/browse/trunk/txtReader/src/com/sun/pdfview/PDFObject.java

Comment: Semantics: You are declaring the class there, not the object. And this is why it's not possible in that form.

Comment: @mario So this is something that can be done in java, but not in PHP?

Comment: Yes. PHP only allows static values in the class declaration, not expressions. You must use the constructor for such purposes, or in your case: write it as inline code right after the class definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the workaround you would need in PHP:

```
class PDFObject {

/** the NULL PDFObject */
public static $nullObj = NULL;

..
}

PDFObject::$nullObj = new PDFObject(null, NULL, null);
```

Normally expression assignments are done in the constructor. But since you want a static class attribute, you will need to resort to inline/global code like that.